# filled quarter circle

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-collection

As usual I am typeseting some old exams. I ran into this image shown below

[image]

I ran into some problems when trying to tikz it up. In the minimal example below I have been able to almost recreate this image, but my method is very rough. I created a half circle, filled it. Then used some trickery with cutting the figure. My main problem is how do I fill a quarter circle? (preferably using tikz euclide)  Now any help improving my figure would be greatly appreciated =)

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\a{3} % Defines the radius for the half circle 
\tkzInit[xmin=-.5,xmax=4,ymin=-.5,ymax=4] \tkzClip 
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){O} \tkzDefPoint(\a,0){S1} \tkzDefPoint(0,\a){S2}
                     \tkzDefPoint(-\a,0){S3} \tkzDefPoint(0,-\a){S4}
\tkzDefPointBy[rotation= center O angle 45](S1) \tkzGetPoint{B}
\tkzDefPoint(\a*2^(-0.5),0){A} \tkzDefPoint(0,\a*2^(-0.5)){C}
\tkzDrawArc[fill=blue,opacity=0.3,ultra thin](O,S1)(S3) 
\tkzDrawArc[color=blue,very thick](O,S1)(S2) 
\tkzDrawSquare[fill=white,color=white](S3,O)
\tkzDrawSquare[fill=white](O,A) \tkzDrawSquare[thick](O,A)
\tkzDefPoint(-0.5,0){x1} \tkzDefPoint[label=above left: $x$](1+\a,0){x2} 
\tkzDefPoint(0,-0.5){y1} \tkzDefPoint[label=below left: $y$](0,1+\a){y2}
\tkzDrawSegments[very thick,-stealth](x1,x2 y1,y2) \tkzDrawSegment[dashed](A,C)
\tkzDrawSegments[ultra thick,white]({-0.5,-0.5},{-0.5,4})
\tkzDrawPoints[fill=black,size=2.5](O,A,B,C)
\tkzLabelPoints[below left](O) \tkzLabelPoints[above right](B)
\tkzLabelPoints[below](A) \tkzLabelPoints[left](C)
\tkzLabelPoint[below](S1){$3$} \tkzLabelPoint[left](S2){$3$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: New MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\a{3} % Defines the radius and clipping. 
\tkzInit[xmin=-.5,xmax=4,ymin=-.5,ymax=4] \tkzClip
% Defines all the neccecary points.
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){O} \tkzDefPoint(\a,0){S1} \tkzDefPoint(0,\a){S2}
\tkzDefPointBy[rotation= center O angle 45](S1) \tkzGetPoint{B}
\tkzDefPoint(\a*2^(-0.5),0){A} \tkzDefPoint(0,\a*2^(-0.5)){C}
% Draws the quarter cirle. (triangle + arc)
\tkzDrawPolygon[fill=blue,opacity=0.3,color=blue](O,S1,S2)
\tkzDrawArc[fill=blue,opacity=0.3,ultra thin](O,S1)(S2) 
\tkzDrawArc[color=blue,very thick](O,S1)(S2) \tkzDrawSegment[color=blue!30!white](S1,S2)
% Draws the square and the dashed line.
\tkzDrawSquare[color=black,thick,fill=white](O,A) \tkzDrawSegment[dashed](A,C)
% Draws the coordinate axis. 
\tkzDefPoint(-0.5,0){x1} \tkzDefPoint[label=above left: $x$](1+\a,0){x2} 
\tkzDefPoint(0,-0.5){y1} \tkzDefPoint[label=below left: $y$](0,1+\a){y2}
\tkzDrawSegments[very thick,-stealth](x1,x2 y1,y2) 
% Draws the points and label them. 
\tkzDrawPoints[fill=black,size=2.5](O,A,B,C)
\tkzLabelPoints[below left](O) \tkzLabelPoints[above right](B)
\tkzLabelPoints[below](A) \tkzLabelPoints[left](C)
\tkzLabelPoint[below](S1){$3$} \tkzLabelPoint[left](S2){$3$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: With recent tkz-euclide, drop the `\usetkzobj{all}` per https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529550/latex-cant-find-file-tkz-obj-angles-tex/529562

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`tkz-euclide`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-euclide-screen.pdf) manual, although is written in french, is full of examples. On page 112 you will find command `\tkzFillSector`. Whitin your first example you can use
`\tkzFillSector[fill=blue,opacity=0.3](O,S1)(S2)` to fill the sector with center on `O` from `S1` to `S2`.

Comment: I actually tried searching trough it, but I am rather weak in the french (as well as the tikz). Thanks though! That simplifies things a great deal!

Answer (score 11):

Some informations to complete Ignasi's answer.

You can find in tkz-euclide some macros about arcs, some macro about sectors. Here it's possible to draw the sector and to fill it at the same time with

```
   \tkzDrawSector[color=blue, thick,fill=blue,fill opacity=0.3](O,S1)(S2)
```

You need only to draw axis after. It's possible to use

```
    \tkzDrawXY[noticks,very thick]
```

to get axis directly.

I added `\tkzClip[space=0.75]` to show the tips of the axes. It's possible to reduce `xmax` and `ymax`.

You can add `tkz in the tags

The complete code :

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
  \tikzset{xlabel style/.style={below left=6 pt,
                              inner sep = 1pt,
                              outer sep = 0pt}}
\tikzset{xaxe style/.style ={>=stealth,->}}
\tikzset{ylabel style/.style={below left = 6 pt,
                              inner sep = 1pt,
                              outer sep = 0pt}}
\tikzset{yaxe style/.style ={>=stealth,->}}    

\def\a{3} % Defines the radius and clipping. 
\tkzInit[xmin=-.4,xmax=4,ymin=-.4,ymax=4] 
% Defines all the neccecary points.
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){O} \tkzDefPoint(\a,0){S1} \tkzDefPoint(0,\a){S2}
\tkzDefPointBy[rotation= center O angle 45](S1) \tkzGetPoint{B}
\tkzDefPoint(\a*2^(-0.5),0){A} \tkzDefPoint(0,\a*2^(-0.5)){C}
% Draws the quarter cirle. (triangle + arc)
\tkzDrawSector[color=blue, thick,fill=blue,fill opacity=0.3](O,S1)(S2) 
% Draws the square and the dashed line.
\tkzDrawSquare[color=black,thick,fill=white](O,A) \tkzDrawSegment[dashed](A,C) 
% Draws the coordinate axis. 
\tkzDrawX[noticks,very thick,below]
\tkzDrawY[noticks,very thick]  
% Draws the points and label them. 
\tkzDrawPoints[fill=black,size=2.5](O,A,B,C)
\tkzLabelPoints[below left](O)  \tkzLabelPoints[above right](B)
\tkzLabelPoints[below](A)       \tkzLabelPoints[left](C)
\tkzLabelPoint[below](S1){$3$}  \tkzLabelPoint[left](S2){$3$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result :

[image]

Comment: The line S1,S2 was only there to hide the gap between the sector and the polygon(triangle). Very nice! I am learning a lot from your examples. Sorry for not being able to read your manual better, I do not know any french. Two questions: 1. is arrowstyle possible to change? I usually use stealth for consistency. 2. Using \caption beneath the image makes too much space http://i.imgur.com/CPDWD.png. Is there any fix? I know removing the \tkzClip[space=0.75] helps, but this removes the arrows.

Comment: A lot of styles are in the file : `tkz-base.cfg ` for example `\tikzset{xaxe style/.style ={>=latex,->}} ` idem for yaxe style. You can modify this style with `\tikzset{xaxe style/.style ={>=stealth,->}} `. If you remove `space=0.75` from `\tkzClip[space=0.75]` you need to change `\tkzInit` and you can use a clip with tikz `\clip (a,b) rectangle (c,d);`. I updated my answer with your requests.