# LaTeX can't find file `tkz-obj-angles.tex'

Tags: tkz-euclide, miktex2.9

PdfLaTeX can't process a file with the following contents:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

When called from cmd.exe (`pdflatex test.tex`), it gives the following error:

```
! I can't find file `tkz-obj-angles.tex'.
<argument> ...\|=12 \input tkz-obj-\tkz@temp .tex
                                                  \catcode `\@ =\csname tkz@...
l.4 \usetkzobj{all}
```

I am using MikTex 2.9, tkz-base version 3.02c, tkz-euclide version 3.02c on Windows 10.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. As far as I understand it, [`\usetkzobj{all}` shouldn't be used with recent `tkz-euclide`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/526267/tikz-error-plotting-function-with-parameters#comment1331128_526275).

Comment: Remove use tkz obj{all} it’s in the doc ! Not necessary with the new version

Comment: @frougon @alain Thank you, I deleted the line `\usetkzobj{all}` and it worked! Could any of you please post this as an answer (or maybe I should post it myself)?

Comment: @alain I've seen this question before I posted but thought it was different from my problem so while a part of it does answer my question, I don't think many people will extract the information needed.

Comment: I voted to reopen because this question addresses a different problem from the one indicated as duplicate.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

With `tkz-euclide` 3.02, `\usetkzobj{all}` (or `\usetkzobjall`) is not necessary according to the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-euclide/doc/TKZdoc-euclide.pdf):

> With the new version 3.02 you don’t need this line anymore. All objects are now
>   loaded.

Removing this command will make the error disappear.