# How to solve a problem with tkz-obj-angles.tex

Tags: macros, packages, tkz-euclide

I am trying to create a figure with TikZ and when compiling an error message appears, stating that it cannot identify `tkz-obj-angles.tex`. After doing some research I saw that the `\usetkzobj{all}` code is no longer needed, as I use an offline editor I still have problems with my figure and I don't know how to solve it.

I opened Overleaf and put the same code, but I was forced to insert the command `\usetkzobj{all}` and the drawing was as I wanted.

Any tips on how to solve this in TeXStudio or TeXMaker?

Comment: Hi and welcome. The version of `tkz-euclide` on Overleaf is old, the one on MikTeX is the latest. Which one do you want to use?

Comment: Update your question by clicking on the `edit` button at the bottom left of your question.

Comment: This site is English speaking, please translate your question into English.

Comment: André I use TeXStudio on Windows and I have MikTex.

Comment: The version on overleaf no longer requires `\usetkzobj{all}`. I spent way to long debugging this based on the other comments here. Hope I save someone some time.

Comment: Related question, [tkz euclide - LaTeX can't find file `tkz-obj-angles.tex' - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529550/latex-cant-find-file-tkz-obj-angles-tex?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Download tkz-obj-eu-angles.tex from http://www.tug.org/texlive//devsrc/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/ then change the name tkz-obj-eu-angles.tex to tkz-obj-angles.tex

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/210739)

Comment: @Mensch this is a link only answer but in this case that is unavoidable. The answer to the question is "download a version from this link to solve your problem", and not "you can find the answer by reading this link".