# Updating from Mint19 to Mint20 breaks tkz-euclide

Tags: pgfkeys, tkz-euclide, texlive-2019, texlive-2018, texlive-2017

I just upgraded from Mint19 to 20. A tex file (20 000 lines) was compiling without error in Mint19. Now I get either 1 or more than 100 errors! The following minimal example shows the dilemma:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
%\usetkzobj{all} 
\begin{document}
   
    \begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-6:1,scale=2.7]
    \coordinate (H2) at ({-sqrt(13)/11},{6/11}) ;
    \coordinate (H1) at ({-11*sqrt(13)/49},{66/49}) ;
    \coordinate (Gn) at ({-sqrt(13)/11},{18/11}) ;
    \fill (H1) circle [radius=0.5pt];
    \fill (H2) circle [radius=0.5pt];
    \fill (Gn) circle [radius=0.5pt];
    \draw[red, thin] (Gn)--(H2);
    \draw[red, thin] (Gn)--(H1);
    \draw[red, thin] (H2)--(H1);
\tkzDrawCircle[diameter, ultrathin](H2,Gn)
\draw [right angle quadrant=1,right angle length=0.9,right angle symbol={H2}{H1}{Gn}];

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

With Mint19 installation this was working fine with the line `%\usetkzobj{all}` commented in.
It fails with Mint20, but the solution seems straightforward: comment it out (from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529550/latex-cant-find-file-tkz-obj-angles-tex)).
When I do this the last two lines gives an error

> Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/right angle
> quadrant...'

and

> Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/ultrathin' ...

With the original file I get more than 100 error mostly from packages pgfkey, pgf and also lots of undefined control sequences such as

> Undefined control sequence. \tkzDrawAltitude...

I checked the tkz-euclide version installed by Mint20: it is 3.02c, so yes I have to comment out the \usetkzobj{all}  line, but this is not a sufficient solution, before I reinstall everything, Mint and TeXLive :-( , may be there is a work-around?

Here the \listfiles result

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
tkz-euclide.sty    2020/01/24 3.02c for euclidan geometry 
tkz-base.sty    2020/01/24 3.02c tkz-base
    tikz.sty    2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
     pgf.sty    2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
  pgfrcs.sty    2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
graphicx.sty    2019/11/30 v1.2a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2019/11/30 v1.4a Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  pdftex.def    2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
  pgfsys.sty    2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
  pgffor.sty    2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
 pgfkeys.sty    
pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
pgfmath.code.tex
pgffor.code.tex
tikz.code.tex
numprint.sty    2012/08/20 v1.39 Print numbers (HH)
   array.sty    2019/08/31 v2.4l Tabular extension package (FMi)
     xfp.sty    2020-02-14 L3 Floating point unit
   expl3.sty    2020-02-14 L3 programming layer (loader) 
l3backend-pdfmode.def    2020-02-03 L3 backend support: PDF mode
  xparse.sty    2020-02-14 L3 Experimental document command parser
      fp.sty    1995/04/02
defpattern.sty    1994/10/12
fp-basic.sty    1996/05/13
fp-addons.sty    1995/03/15
 fp-snap.sty    1995/04/05
  fp-exp.sty    1995/04/03
fp-trigo.sty    1995/04/14
  fp-pas.sty    1994/08/29
fp-random.sty    1995/02/23
  fp-eqn.sty    1995/04/03
  fp-upn.sty    1996/10/21
 fp-eval.sty    1995/04/03
tkz-base.cfg
tkz-tools-modules.tex
tkz-lib-marks.tex
tkz-tools-intersections.tex
tkz-tools-angles.tex
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 ***********
```

Comment: Send an email to Alain Matthes, maintainer of `tkz-euclide` to see what he can do. You will find his email address by clicking on his name at the bottom of page 2 of the [manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/tkz-euclide) *Please report typos or any other comments to this documentation to: Alain Matthes*

Comment: the current version (as in texlive 2020) is 3.06c so perhaps  the issue is fixed, you could get an update from ctan or the git source repo https://github.com/tkz-sty/tkz-euclide (where issues can also be reported) (unrelated but size commands do not take an argument  `\Huge{...}` the brace group does not limit the scope of `\Huge` which applies to the whole document.

Comment: with the current version I get `! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/ultrathin' `  (ignore any errors after the first)

Comment: in texive 2016 the ultrathin error goes but the right angle quadrant key used in the test file still gave errors, has that example ever worked?

Comment: Yes the right angle quadrant was working. I had no error with this code... and \Huge is not part of the initial document :-)

Comment: can you fix the example so it can be run, and add `\listfiles` and then show the log from the working version.

Comment: There is a definition of `right angle quadrant` in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21752, I'm guessing you have that, or some similar definition, in your full document? Edit: `ultrathin` should presumably be `ultra thin`?